# Collada (.dae) file not load in my scene, how to fix it?

Tags: objective-c, scenekit, collada

I try to load a Collada (.dae) to a scene and display the file on phone screen.

I download Collada file from my server in a zip file named 0002.scnassets.zip. 
I unzip the file and get the folder 0002.scnassets with inside the Collada and texture.
The folder is inside Documents directory of the app.

I tried this

```c
//download zip from server
//unzip

//try to display
self.Objectview.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"ObjectScene.scn"];
SCNScene *ObjectS = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"/0002.scnassets/0002.dae"];
NSLog(@"Children :%@", ObjectS.rootNode.childNodes);
[self.Objectview.scene.rootNode addChildNode:[ObjectS.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"0002" recursively:YES]];
self.Objectview.allowsCameraControl = YES;
self.Objectview.autoenablesDefaultLighting = YES;
[self.Objectview play:(nil)];
```

When I execute the code, zip are downloaded and unzipped correctly. But when I try to create the scene with the file: 0002.dae, the log just after said : `Children :(null)`
So it's like I can't have access to the Collada file.

I try this as well:

```c
self.Objectview.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"/0004.scnassets/0004.dae"];
NSLog(@"%lu", self.Objectview.scene.rootNode.childNodes.count);
```

To add directly the Collada to my scene view without .scn file, but didn't work. I get from NSLog : `0`

So I want to display the Collada file on the scene view. Any ideas ?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

To make sure that the file exists, I check it with this :

```c
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *getPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"0004.scnassets/0004.dae"]];
NSLog(getPath);

BOOL isDir = NO;
BOOL isFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:getPath isDirectory:&isDir];
NSLog(@"is Dir : %d",isDir);
NSLog(@"is File : %d", isFile);
```

from these ligne I get the path and `is Dir : 0` and `is File : 1`

So the file exist. I tried to load a scene from `getPath`but didn't work :

```c
SCNScene *ObjectS = [SCNScene sceneNamed:getPath];
NSLog(@"child ObjectScene : %@", ObjectS.rootNode.childNodes);
```

I get `child ObjectScene : (null)`

Comment: this might be helpful: https://the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/

Comment: I got this error: 'scenekit COLLADA files are not supported on this platform'. I ended using scn file in server instead.

Comment: @AlokSubedi I tried this but nothing, I don't have error message and don't have the Collada file displayed on the scene phone. When I check if the node with the object is here I get nothing. It's like the ligne ```SCNScene *ObjectS = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"0004.dae" inDirectory:path options:nil];``` doesn't work

Comment: I tried your second answer. I converted Collada file to scenekit file (.scn). I can download the file from server but I can't display it with the ligne ```SceneView.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:/0002.scn];``` Any idea ?